# How does the React-Router algorithm work?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, reactjs, react-router

Can anyone explain me how React-Router assembles the components together?

What I mean is: Take for example this code from the React-Router documentation ...

```js
<Router history={browserHistory}>
  <Route path="/" component={App}>
    <Route path="about" component={About}/>
    <Route path="users" component={Users}>
      <Route path="/user/:userId" component={User}/>
      </Route>
    <Route path="*" component={NoMatch}/>
  </Route>
</Router>
```

Let's say I enter the URL "/inbox/messages/" into the adressbar.

I guess it calls first the "App" component and incorporates that into the DOM-tree.

**But how does it goes on?**

They use they the "this.props.children" property.

```js
const App = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>App</h1>
        <ul>
          <li><Link to="/about">About</Link></li>
          <li><Link to="/inbox">Inbox</Link></li>
        </ul>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    )
  }
})
```

But "App" has several children. Right?

How does it decide what it has to incorporate next?
**How does the algorithm work?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far the react-router documentation says for url matching they use a DFS(Depth First Search) You can find it [react-router Algorithm](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/RouteMatching.md#route-matching).
And you can find about DFS [here](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~heap/270F02/node36.html)